# Make parallax image smaller and fit in specific place

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax and put my image in a container that will resize the actual image. Ill try to explain better with 2 pictures:
Here is how it looks know

[image]

Here is how I kind of want it to look like:
[image]

I want the images to shrink a little and see more of them;
Here is my code up to know:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 services-container">
    <section class="parallax img-responsive" style="background: url('<%= serv.imagePath %>')">
    </section>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.services-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e3e3;
    height: 300px;
}

.parallax {
     /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 300px;


    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you try `background-size: 100% auto` ? And maybe you should use `height` instead of `min-height` for your `.parallax` class

Comment: Hy @Brewal i tried that and alsow background-size: 50% and nothing changes

Comment: Hy @MarouenMhiri it's getting closer to what i want but the images are still very big and if i try background-size: 50% it resize the image with the center  of the image in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at the "CSS Specificity hierarchy" (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). You are using a shorthand for background as inline-style in your section tag. This will override all the background-styles present in your css. So Just replace background with background-image. This should solve the issue:

```
<section class="parallax img-responsive" style="background-image: url('<%= serv.imagePath %>')">
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
background-size: 50%;
background-position-x: right;
background-position-y: center;
```

and this will put my images in the desired parts of the screen.

Comment: That doesn't seems very clean. It seems like your `section.parallax` doesn't have the expected width. You should try to make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if you want more advices